# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.blueweb.Blueweb

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
    Blueweb obj4 = snapshot.getValue(Blueweb.class);
    adapter.add(obj4);
}
```

I'm getting Error in this second line.. tell me what's wrong in this code and how to solve it.

MyAdapterCode:

```
public class BluewebAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Blueweb> {
    public BluewebAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, List<Blueweb> bluewebList) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView ==null){
            convertView = ((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.message_item,parent,false);
        }
        ImageView photoImageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.photoImageView);
        TextView textTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textTextView);
        TextView nameTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);

        Blueweb obj = getItem(position);
        boolean isText = obj.getImageURl()==null;
        if(isText){
            textTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            photoImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            nameTextView.setText(obj.getText());
        }
        else{
            textTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            photoImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Glide.with(photoImageView.getContext()).
                    load(obj.getImageURl()).
                    into(photoImageView);
        }
        nameTextView.setText(obj.getName());
                return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please: 1) change the first snippet to show the entire `ChildEventListener`, including the call to `addChildEventListener`, 2) add the JSON at the location of your database that you add the listener to (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: i don't get you :(

Answer (score 0):

```
snapshot.getValue(Blueweb.class)
```

returns String type that you try to convert to Blueweb type

Try code below:

```
String obj4 = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
```

Comment: if i add String to it. i can't able to add obj4 in my adapter

Comment: i added see it @Rajab Mamedli